# Tomcat7 JDBC connection pool -> Connection has been abandoned

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, connection-pooling

I have the following configuration for the JDBC connection pool

```
initialSize="2"
minIdle="10"
maxIdle="50"
maxActive="100"
maxWait="15000"
jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ResetAbandonedTimer"
removeAbandoned="true"
removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
logAbandoned="true"
testOnBorrow="true"
testOnReturn="true"
testWhileIdle="true"
useEquals="false"
fairQueue="false"
timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="300000"
minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="300000"
validationInterval="10000"
validationQuery="SELECT 1"
```

The application is a standard Java+Spring+Hibernate environment, and the database is PostgreSQL. I have been using those configs for a while, and everything was fine...

Recently the following exception started to appear

```
Sep 10, 2015 5:25:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool abandon
    WARNING: Connection has been abandoned PooledConnection[org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection@3eb948ed]:java.lang.Exception
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getThreadDump(ConnectionPool.java:1063)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:780)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:619)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:188)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:70)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1351)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:59)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:67)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:110)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:420)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:257)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)

10 Sep 2015 17:25:57,591 WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08006
10 Sep 2015 17:25:57,592 ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:316)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractJPAQuery.java:219)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.uniqueResult(AbstractJPAQuery.java:295)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.uniqueResult(AbstractJPAQuery.java:281)
    at com.mysema.query.support.ProjectableQuery.singleResult(ProjectableQuery.java:75)
```

I don't have any new query running too long, but I guess that this happens because the connection is not returned to the pool properly... I tried to play around the configurations, but the same happens, though in rare cases .

I'd just like to know if the configurations are fine for the application with an average load, and if there is any chance to improve the connection pool life.

Note: When I decrease `timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis` and
`minEvictableIdleTimeMillis` it starts to happen more often.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look at how you're handling EntityTransactions, because one of them somewhere isn't being committed or rolled back. Make sure you're rolling them back as well if you're catching a NoResultException. If not that, put timing hooks with print statements around your queries to see which ones are taking a long time.

Answer (score 3):

Increasing `removeAbandonedTimeout` will alleviate the problem but not fix it. This issue can be caused by not closing the connections properly or by queries that take too long.

See if you can monitor the queries that are run, time them and see if they are being closed correctly.